# slicing and replacing a number in R

Tags: r, slice

I have a number like this example:

fferc114

and would like to:
1- remove the first 3 elements
2- keep the 2nd 3 elements

the expected output would look like this:

expected output:

dfer**

I am trying to that in R using the following code but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

```
trying to that
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
x <- "E431250000326"
paste0(substr(x, 4, 6), "-", substr(x, 11, nchar(x)))

[1] "125-326"
```

Or if you want to subtract the numbers:

```
as.numeric(substr(x, 4, 6)) - as.numeric(substr(x, 11, nchar(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach

```
string <- "E431250000326"
sub(".{3}(.{3})(.{4})(.{3})", "\\1-\\3", string)
#[1] "125-326"
```

As described in the question this removes first 3 elements, selects (using capture group) next 3 elements, replaces next 4 elements with `"-"` and selects next 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

We can specifically match a digit to capture the group

```
sub(".{3}(\\d{3})\\d{4}(\\d{3})", "\\1-\\2", string)
#[1] "125-326"
```

#### data

```
string <- "E431250000326"
```